# What does this in game dialogue say?

Tags: starcraft-2

There's some in game dialogue [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0SLDzsVSRAk&t=29m), sadly it's incomprehensible due to the caster's voices. Maybe it's the Protoss talking? But we're hearing the cam-guy's sound and he's not selecting anything special there.

So, why does this dialogue happen and what does it say?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're referring to the quote I think you are, the unit is saying:

"The [Firstborn](http://starcraft.wikia.com/wiki/Protoss) shall persevere."

This appears to be [one of the quotes spoken](http://starcraft.wikia.com/wiki/StarCraft_II_unit_quotations#Adept) when an [Adept](http://starcraft.wikia.com/wiki/Adept) unit finishes training. In the video, they show the production queues in the top left, and what looks to be an Adept disappears from the top queue just as the line plays, showing that their training just completed. You can hear the quote at the start of this video of their unit quotes:

Comment: Indeed, this is Adept's "unit ready" sound. By the way, very high quality of both answer and question! I like to think that is because we're in [SC2 community](http://i0.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/newsfeed/000/343/462/79a.gif).

Comment: What I thought to be a response must be a quote from the one most left in the terran production tab then. Thanks :)